# How to turn off "Unused definition violation" in phpstorm

Tags: svn, phpstorm, jshint

Im working on a file that is part of an SDK. When I commit the file to svn in phpstorm, I get a warning about `Unused definition SomeFunction` where `SomeFunction` is a prototype function of `MySDK`.

```
/* 
 * A function that does stuff
 * @public
 * @method SomeFunction
 * 
 */
MySDK.prototype.SomeFunction = function(){
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

The sdk project is in a separate project from the code that uses it, which is probably why this warning is coming up, but i honestly have no idea which plugin is throwing the error.

Also not all the functions are throwing an error, but their Comment Block and signatures are almost identical. Maybe it only shows the first *`n`* warnings.

Im open to any resolution, but preferably best practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be strictly `PHPstorm` problem so here is what I believe to be an appropriate response.

```
/*
 * A function that does stuff
 * @public
 * @method SomeFunction
 */

//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols,JSUnresolvedVariable
MySDK.prototype.SomeFunction = function(){
    console.log(arguments);
};
```

What I did:

`//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols,JSUnresolvedVariable` disables those two specific inspection types for `MySDK.prototype.SomeFunction` only.

Added `;` after `}` because PHPstorm gave a weak warning about it too.

Hope that helps, you can ignore more inspections in certain scenarios when you hit `alt+enter` while specific line of code is focused.

Comment: I've moved on to intelliJ, but "you can ignore more inspections... alt+enter" is very useful. Thanks!